# Altering text within Angular .html

Tags: html, angular

I hope I can make sense with this question

is it possible to alter your text label within Angular .html layout depending on some criteria in your query?  For example below, possibly I'd like to interactively alter the "placeholder="Service Date" to something other than 'Service Date', depending on some criteria in my query in the corresponding .ts file, some indicator field.  Effectively, if indicator='x' then placeholder="something else"

is that possible to accomplish?

```
<div class="row">
    <mat-form-field>
       <input matInput placeholder="Service Date" name="serviceDate" value="
          {{claim.serviceDate | date}}" disabled="disabled">
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, you're able to alter the `value`, right? Why not try a similar technique with `placeholder`?

Comment: Did you try placeholder="{{indicator=='x'? 'something else':'Service Date'}}"

Answer (score 1):

By setting the placeholder as a binding you can then use an expression that can be evaluated either in the component or the view itself

```
<input matInput [placeholder]=“<any expression>” name="serviceDate" value="
      {{claim.serviceDate | date}}" disabled="disabled">
```

Where `<any expression>` can be a variable, a ternary expression or anything that can be evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

It is good practice to move(wrap) some expression logic into **method** of class and use it in template. It's helps to keep template clean and easy to test.

**Template:**

```
<div class="row">
        <mat-form-field>
           <input matInput placeholder="{{getPlaceholder()}}" name="serviceDate" value="
              {{claim.serviceDate | date}}" disabled="disabled">
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
```

**Component class:**

```
  class SomeComponent:
    {
      getPlaceholder(): string {
        return this.indicator == x ? "placeHolder1" : "placeHolder2";
      }
    }
```